# How to exclude methods from test coverage in EclEmma?

Tags: testing, eclipse-plugin, junit3, eclemma

I am using EclEmma plugin for checking test coverage for maven project.
It works, but it gives coverage results based on all the functions in the **testing** class. As there is some getter, setter and private functions are there, i want to exclude them from calculating test coverage. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: i think EclEmma currently not providing such service. :)

Comment: One more thing i would like to add, i s if you want to exclude some method in a class from coverage analysis better analysis the coverage of methods you needs. EclEmma provide details of each method coverage and with respect to different counter, like branch, complexity, line, instruction, etc. I solved my problem by these measurements. hope this information will help someone.